# NoClassDefFoundError using Xerces in OSGi environment

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, xerces, apache-servicemix

I've built a simple bundle which instantiate a `org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver` class.
In my pom, I've had these dependencies and plugin :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin to create bundle -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.4</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>myXMLResolver</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- xerces is provided in /lib/endorsed/ folder of ServiceMix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
           <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_5</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</build>
```

Testing the bundle "locally" (within the IDE) is working fine.

Deploying it into the */deploy* folder is also fine (its status is "Active").

When running it (through Camel route), I get this stacktrace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/resolver/CatalogManager
      at org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver.init(Unknown Source)[:]
      at org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)[:]
      at org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)[:]
      at myXMLResolver.MainBean.run(MainBean.java:17)[241:test.myXMLResolver:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_95]
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_95]
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_95]
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_95]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)[199:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.1]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)[199:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.1]
      at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)[199:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.1]
      ... 19 more
```

If I'm not wrong, the class `CatalogManager` from package `org.apache.xml.resolver` existed during compilation but not in run-time. So I deploy `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver` dependency into */deploy* folder.
When executing in Karaf console the command `bundle:headers <xmlresolver_bundle_id>`, I get :

```
Export-Package = 
...
org.apache.xml.resolver;uses:="org.apache.xml.resolver.helpers,javax.xml.parsers,org.apache.xml.resolver.readers";version=1.2,
...
```

Nevertheless, same stacktrace appears.
Even if I add the package `org.apache.xml.resolver` in the `<Import-Package>` I get the same error.

Any idea of what's going on ?

I'm using ServiceMix 6.1.0 (w/ Karaf 3.0.5), running on Java 7.

---

**Edit** :

Here is the bundle's MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1461311084908
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_72-internal
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: myXMLResolver
Bundle-SymbolicName: test.myXMLResolver
Bundle-Version: 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: myXMLResolver;version="0.0.1";uses:="org.apache.camel,org.apache.xerces.util"
Import-Package: org.apache.camel;version="[2.16,3)",org.apache.xerces.util;version="[2.11,3)"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
Tool: Bnd-2.4.1.201501161923
```

If I add the package `org.apache.xml.resolver` in the `<Import-Package>`, `Import-Package` from MANIFEST become : `org.apache.camel;version="[2.16,3)",org.apache.xerces.util;version="[2.11,3)",org.apache.xml.resolver;version="[1.2,2)"`

---

**Edit #2** : workaround

A workaround can be done :

1. Put the bundle `org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver` in
   `<SMX_HOME>/lib/endorsed` folder
2. In the file `<SMX_HOME>/etc/config.properties`, add
   `org.apache.xml.resolver` to the property
   `org.osgi.framework.system.package.extra`.

But it doesn't look like a clean method...

---

**Edit #3** : issue opened on Jira : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SM-3020

Comment: Can you post the MANIFEST.MF of the bundle? This is much more interesting than the POM, since the manifest is used at runtime whereas the POM is a build-time artifact.

Comment: Actually it looks like the problem is not in your bundle, but in whichever bundle contains the class `org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver`.